# Suspending keyboard when user press on home button?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, keyboard, uitextfield

I am developing an application were everything is working fine, except one i.e. when user press on home while keyboard is in active and again opens my application the view frame bounds are changing and moving out of bounds. My expected result is keyboard should get suspended or the view should stay in the same position when it is come back from background to foreground with keyboard in-active state.

I hope people understand my scenario and reply ASAP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my question, i hope people can use my solution. Below is the code what I have done,

Add the below line of code in your RootViewController file (i.e. which view is coming at first when you open your APP).

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedNotification:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

And then add a private method as below

```
- (void) receivedNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
if ([username isFirstResponder])
{
    [username resignFirstResponder];
}
else if ([password isFirstResponder])
{
    [password resignFirstResponder];
}
}
```

I hope it help some body,Thank u.

Further assistance please see the mentioned link,

Comment: change "- (void) receivedNotification:(NSNotification *) notification" with "- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application" the observer is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

there is a method in the app delegate

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

this method is fired when you press the home button.
do the necessary changes(textField resignFirstResponder) in this method and it should work fine i guess.

**EDIT** here's the code

in the class where you have your textfield create a method

```
-(void)performWhenHomeBtnprssed
{
[MytextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

then in

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  [myClassObj performWhenHomeBtnprssed];
}
```

also i agree with  @valexa you should find the root cause of the problem

Comment: thanks for your suggestion also I know that when user press home button the runs to background/foreground operation, but how to resign the text field in these method, please can you give a example code or snippet.

Answer (score 0):

In software development it is always better to address the root causes than to patch the effect, in your case there are problems with the positioning of your views and you should address that, foreground/background cycling should not affect the views positioning.

Comment: How should I position the views when the app goes to background/foreground. Can you please give me a example. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: properly™ ....... if they reposition as a result of foreground/background cycling then you are doing something wrong